How come I can capture an object being constructed in the lambda doing the construction?
Consider the following code:
int x = [&x](){
    std::cout << "Inside lambda, x is " << x << '\n';
    x = 5;
    return 23;
}();
std::cout << "x is " << x << '\n';

This compiles and runs! And without any warnings, too! I'm actually a bit shocked. What's going on here? How am I allowed to capture an unconstructed object and read and write from it?
And if you think "This is fine, since int is default-constructible, so probably x gets default constructed" - then try this:
struct Int {
    int v;
    Int(int v):v{v}{}
};

static_assert(!std::is_constructible_v<Int>);
static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<Int, int>);

int main()
{
    Int x = [&x](){
        std::cout << "Inside lambda, x is " << x.v << '\n';
        x = 5;
        return 23;
    }();
    std::cout << "x is " << x.v << '\n';
}

and that also compiles and runs.

I don't feel competent  to find the proper chapter in the standard, but I would say it's because the address of Int x is already known, so you can use a reference to it.

:7:53: warning: 'x' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]: I'm guessing that x location exists before the object construction starts, allowing to take a reference
it "works" for the same reason void* x = &x; is totally fine. I am not a language lawyer, but I know you may use the name of the thing you initialize for its initializer. Read before initialization is done, is still UB of course

You can use the address of a not-yet-constructed-object, or a reference to a not-yet-constructed-object.  Accessing that not-yet-constructed object is undefined behavior.  There are a few use cases where stowing a pointer or reference for later (after construction) is useful.  I've used it for saving whether or not an object was declared const for the constructor (for debugging a bizarre const-related bug, once upon a time).

It would be interesting  to find the relevant part of the standard. I found "an initializer in the definition of a variable can consist of arbitrary expressions involving literals and previously declared variables and functions, regardless of the variable’s storage duration." And the variable is already declared on the left-hand side of "=" but the "arbitrary" part is obviously to be nuanced...

Printing x in the lambda (before assigning to it) is accessing the value of an uninitialised int, so causes undefined behaviour (getting a value of zero then is either luck or a property of your compiler).    Undefined behaviour is not required to be diagnosed.     After assigning to x, accessing its value would be fine.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: Care to make that an answer?

IMHO the question is not really a duplicate and doesn't have a proper answer yet. (the linked dupe is less general than this one). There are things to clarify between point of declaration, storage duration,  (implicit) lifetime.
